# Oriented graphs with no infinite paths

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

This question is based on a [deleted question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3487450/7062) by user [Ethan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/50290/ethan). I don't think it's what Ethan originally meant to ask, but I thought it was an interesting question.

Let $G = (V,E)$ be an infinite (simple and undirected) graph. An *orientation* of $G$ is a choice of direction $x\to y$ or $y\to x$ for each edge $\{x,y\}\in E$. Given an orientation of $G$, an infinite path is a sequence of vertices $(v_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that either $v_i\to v_{i+1}$ for all $i$ (this is a *forwards* path) or $v_{i+1}\to v_i$ for all $i$ (this is a *backwards* path). Note that any cycle in the orientation $a_1\to a_2\to \dots \to a_n\to a_1$ gives rise to infinite paths, both forwards and backwards.

**Question:** Which graphs admit an orientation with no infinite paths?

If $G$ contains an infinite clique $C$, then any orientation of $G$ has an infinite path. *Proof:* Enumerate a countably infinite subset $C'$ of $C$ by $C' = (v_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$. For each pair $(v_i,v_j)$ with $i<j$, color this pair red if $v_i\to v_j$ and blue if $v_j\to v_i$. By Ramsey's theorem, there is an infinite monochromatic subset $H\subseteq C'$. If $H$ is monochromatic red, then its vertices (enumerated in increasing order) form an infinite forwards path. If $H$ is monochromatic blue, then its vertices (enumerated in increasing order) form an infinite backwards path.

On the other hand, if $G$ is $k$-colorable, then it admits an orientation in which every path has length at most $k$. This is the easy direction of the proof of the [Gallai-Hasse-Roy-Vitaver theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallai%E2%80%93Hasse%E2%80%93Roy%E2%80%93Vitaver_theorem).  The hard direction does not apply here, because having no infinite path is a much weaker assumption than the existence of a finite bound on the length of paths.

What happens if $G$ has no infinite clique, but is not $k$-colorable for any $k$?

Comment: If it has no infinite cliques, then for any infinite sequence of vertices you can take two non-adjacent vertices and orient all of their adjacent edges towards them. If you can do this for any infinite sequence of vertices, this should complete the characterization.

Comment: Here is an example of a graph $G=(V,E)$ which is triangle-free (so it has no infinite clique) but every orientation has an infinite path: $$V=\{(x,y):x,y\in\mathbb N, x\lt y\}$$ $$E=\{\{(x,y),(y,z)\}:x,y,z\in\mathbb N,x\lt y\lt z\}$$

Comment: Alex, I think this *is* what Ethan was trying to ask. Of course your formulation is much clearer.

Comment: @broncoAbierto I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Let $\kappa$ be a regular infinite cardinal. Here is an example of a directed graph of chromatic number $\kappa$ with no infinite path. The vertex set is $\kappa\times\kappa$. There is a directed edge from $(\alpha,\beta)$ to $(\alpha',\beta')$ if $\alpha\lt\alpha'$ and $\beta\gt\beta'$.

Comment: I doubt that your question is answerable. My guess is that there is no better "characterization" than the one you gave: "admits an orientation with no infinite paths". I can't imagine how one could prove that.

Comment: @bof You can't have an oriented path if every sequence has two "sinks". That's the idea. But perhaps you cannot achieve that just with the condition "no infinite cliques".

Comment: Just reread and noticed it can be backwards, so never mind.